# Why is the full correlation matrix not getting calculated in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pearson-correlation

I have a dataset with 4 variables(Bearing 1 to Bearing 4) and 20152319 no of observations. It looks like this:

[image: A snapshot of the dataset I am working on]

Now, I am trying to find the correlation matrix of the 4 variables. The code I use is this:

```
corr_mat = Data.corr(method = 'pearson')
print(corr_mat)
```

However in the result, I get the correlation information for only Bearing 2 to Bearing 4. Bearing 1 is nowhere to be seen. I am providing a snapshot of the result down below:

[image: Snapshot of the correlation matrix]

I have tried removing NULL values from each of the variables and also tried looking for missing values but nothing works. What is interesting is that, if I isolate the first two variables (Bearing 1 and Bearing 2) and then try to find the correlation matrix between them, Bearing 1 does not come up and the matrix is a 1x1 matrix with only Bearing 2

Any explanation on why this occurs and how to solve it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is first column numeric? What is `print (df['Bearing 1'].dtype)` ?

Comment: @jezrael it is an object

Answer (score 2):

Try to see if the first column 'Bearing 1' is numeric.

```
Data.dtypes # This will show the type of each column

cols = Data.columns # Saving column names to a variable
Data[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') # Converting the columns to numeric
```

Now apply your Calculations,

```
corr_mat = Data.corr(method = 'pearson')
print(corr_mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dtype` of first column is `object`, so pandas by default omit it. Solution is convert it to numeric:

```
Data['Bearing 1'] = Data['Bearing 1'].astype(float)
```

Or if some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for parse these values to `NaN`s:

```
Data['Bearing 1'] = pd.to_numeric(Data['Bearing 1'], errors='coerce')
```

If want convert all columns to numeric:

```
Data = Data.astype(float)
```

Or:

```
Data = Data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```